# Query mail logs for xp_sendmail

Tags: sql-server-2000, database-mail

Using SQL Server 2008, I can query `sysmail_log` and other tables to see the results of sql emails.

Is anything remotely similar available for querying email logs in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - xp_SendMail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `xp_sendmail` I believe the only history you will find is:

- Critical events that were severe enough to warrant an entry into SQL Server's error log. This does not include things like bounces, undeliverables, malformed addresses, etc.
- The history of the e-mail account that is used to start Outlook on the server. So for example you will see sent items there, and bounces / undeliverables in their inbox (if the account accepts incoming mail). This will depend, of course, on what's backing that account - e.g. Exchange.

There are many reasons this feature was deprecated in favor of Database Mail. Unfortunately you need to upgrade to take advantage of better functionality.